# apply onclick event to an option

Tags: php, zend-framework, onclick, mootools, zend-form

I am using zend form to create a form. I am also using mootools for javascript.

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'alone', array(
    'label' => 'Are you going to be taking part with anyone else?',
    'required' => true,
    'onClick' => 'showFields();',
    'multiOptions' => array(
        'yes' => 'Yes',
        'no' => 'No'
    ))
);
```

At the moment, the onclick event works if any option is selected. How do i get it to work for just yes being selected?

Comment: make the first line of your `showFields()` function verify that `yes` is selected before doing anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this...

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'alone', array(
    'label' => 'Are you going to be taking part with anyone else?',
    'required' => true,
    'onClick' => 'showFields(this);',
    'multiOptions' => array(
        'yes' => 'Yes',
        'no' => 'No'
    ))
);
```

And in your function...

```
function showFields(elem)
{
    if(elem.value != 'yes')
        return false;

    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: when trying this solution i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined `

Comment: sorted that problem by using id instead of value. however, when the page loads the fields that are meant to hidden are shown. When i click no however, they go away